# Proving monotonicity of a function given a differential inequality

Tags: calculus

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable with $f(2)<f'(x)<f(3)$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Prove that $f$ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$.

I think this could be be proved by contradiction but I'm not sure what to choose. Letting  $f'(x)\leq 0$ was my first thought since a contradiction would instantly yield the result but it could be the case that $f'(x)\geq0$ and still be strictly increasing if $f'(x)=0$ doesn't happen on an interval. But doing that requires a lot of cases for $x$ and it didn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c$ in $(2, 3)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(3) - f(2)}{3-2} = f(3) - f(2)$.

So, $f(2) < f(3) - f(2) < f(3)$ which is equivalent to $f(2) > 0$.

So, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f'(x) > 0$ and $f$ is strictly increasing.

I hope my solution is correct and can help you.

Comment: Yup, that's probably how it should've been done. I got tunnel visioned trying to get a contradiction. Thanks.

Comment: Reasoning by contradiction is often useful in similar exercises, but here, given that $3-2 = 1$, the Mean Value Theorem helps us a lot!

Comment: I kind of underestimated the exercise and tried to prove a general case of $f(a)<f'(x)<f(b)$ since it seemed very interesting if it turned out to be the case and by that point I had pretty much lost the point of the problem. I think I might've come by a similar problem before but now I think I'll be more careful about the values given and what that could imply. Maybe I should even write down the cases I see. Again, cheers.